# How to use java String.replaceAll(string regex,string replacement) to get what I want?

Tags: java, regex, string

Codes:

```
  String etr = "fdsfsdaf\nTKT:1101234567890FSDFD";
```

the format is like ".+\nTKT:\d{13}.+".

how to get first 3 numberic after "\nTKT:" using String.replaceAll to implement? In this example, I want to get is "110".  Exclude Matcher,Pattern and Other String method like indexOf(). Because I found the Regex include "?:","?<",but I have tried but failed,something like":

```
      replaceAll(".+\nTKT:(?=[\\d{3}])\\d{10}.+","");
```

Thanks in advance.I just know some basic use for Regex.

Comment: So you want to remove `110`?

Comment: no, I want to get 110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing,you should match it

```
Matcher m=Pattern.compile(".+\nTKT:(\\d{3})\\d{10}.+").matcher(input);
if(m.find())
{
    m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Hi,Anirudh,thanks for your answer,it is correct,but there has some other problem, if the etr doesn't match the regex, how can let the replaceAll result is EMPTY?Is it can implemented just by modify the Regex?

Comment: Hmm,exclude Matcher,Pattern.. though this is an correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can `replaceAll(".+\nTKT:(\\d{3})\\d{10}.+", "$1");`

Comment: upvoted, this answer is answered by Anirudh before.As I want to set the replaceAll result Empty when the regex is not match the input,he modified the answer. Anymore,thank you.